# Compare columns from two CSVs and merge on matches

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I have two CSV files and am trying to merge them based on the first column in the first file matching the third column in the second file. They lines are not sorted.

**file1.csv:**

```
android,1,2
osx,2,5
```

**file2.csv:**

```
Converting,:Developer::|[E],android,Exact,,,,8,31
Converting,:Developer::|[E],osx,Exact,,,,8,31
Converting,:Developer::|[E],windows,Exact,,,,8,31
```

and would desire the following **output.csv:**

```
Converting,:Developer::|[E],android,Exact,,,,8,31,1,2
Converting,:Developer::|[E],osx,Exact,,,,8,31,2,5
Converting,:Developer::|[E],windows,Exact,,,,8,31,,
```

I have tried every example of

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR.....
```

that I could find on here but just cant seem to get it right.

Comment: Are there always three fields on `file1.csv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `join` for this

```
join -1 1 -2 3 -t ',' -a 2 -o 2.{1..9} 1.{2..3}  <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv)
```

`-1` and `-2` specifies which field from the files to compare
`-t` specifies the seperator to use for the fields
`-a 2` says to print lines in `<file2>` that do not match
`-o` configures the output based on `<file>.<field>`

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for the job [is probably `join`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259306/22222) but since you mentioned `awk`, here's another approach:

```
$ awk -F',' -vOFS="," 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;b[$1]=$3; next}{print $0,a[$3],b[$3]}' file1 file2
Converting,:Developer::|[E],android,Exact,,,,8,31,1,2
Converting,:Developer::|[E],osx,Exact,,,,8,31,2,5
Converting,:Developer::|[E],windows,Exact,,,,8,31,,
```

It uses two arrays, `a` and `b`, which have the 1st field of `file1` as keys and the 2nd and 3rd as values, respectively. The `FNR==NR{...next}` ensures that only the 1st file is saved in the arrays. Then, when processing the second file, we print the file's line (`$0`), followed by the values corresponding to its first field from arrays `a` and `b`. The `-vOFS=","` sets the output field separator to a comma so we get the desired output format.

Alternatively, slightly more cryptically:

```
$ awk -F',' -vOFS="," 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2","$3;next}{print $0,(a[$3]?a[$3]:",")}' file1 file2
Converting,:Developer::|[E],android,Exact,,,,8,31,1,2
Converting,:Developer::|[E],osx,Exact,,,,8,31,2,5
Converting,:Developer::|[E],windows,Exact,,,,8,31,,
```